# Change height of a button in Bootstrap's API

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, frontend

Is there a way to increase the line height of a button in Bootstrap's api cause im having issues creating them

Here is my code:

```
@import "bootstrap-5.3.3/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap-5.3.3/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap-5.3.3/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap-5.3.3/scss/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap-5.3.3/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap-5.3.3/scss/utilities";

$input-btn-line-height: 3;

$utilities: (
    "margin-top-and-bottom": (
        property: margin-bottom,
        class: mb,
        values: (
            "03": 0.3rem,
        ),
    ),
);

@import "bootstrap-5.3.3/scss/bootstrap";
```

Any feedback will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind i solved it. i just had to place in another scss file